# Database Structure for customer tax preparation

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

[Database Design of Customer Tax Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8SJM.jpg)

I need to maintain a set of info about Customers and their expenses during the year.
*FaceValue, Rent, UtilitiesCost* are the tables which stores expenses during the year.
The last column stores Sum of the year. Is that a good practice?

*CustomerTaxReport* table needs all the total value of each table against **CustomerNo**.
Storing information like this is difficult to maintain. If there's a modification in one record, then I have to re-calculate all required records.

What is the best way to overcome this problem? If I use Triggers then, I think it will cause performance issues.

Comment: You don't need to have `FaceValue, Rent, UtilitiesCost` as different tables rather just have one table in place of these and add a type column to signify that row is referring to which column.

Comment: A database is a persistent store of data.  It is not a display mechanism (do columns when reading).  Do not compute things that can be computed later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would recomend to change:

- Move Month values from tables' columns to rows. For this just add some `month` and fill it with the start of corresponding month: '2020-03-01' for the March. Add `value` column to store amount
- If you need a `year` as a separate period - jus add a new column and fill either `month` or `year`
- Make `CustomerTaxReport` query instead of a table

It is most likely `int` is not a good type for storing amounts of money.

Comment: If the year total is computable, do _not_ include it as a column or row; recompute on the fly.